# IOS: contextual menu "paste" en UITextField in file xib no show/working

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, xcode

I hope you can help me

I have a .xib file with a respective class that inherits from a UIViewController. Inside the xib you have a UITextField text field, when trying to paste a string as url, text or number. Pressing the UITextField does not appear the contextual menu to paste the previously copied string.

I have tried the same execution a storyboard, with the respective UIViewController and it works without problems, but if it is in a xib it does not work

Is there any way to do this in xib?
[image]